# Only allow to send email from Office 365 but not Salesforce

Tags: lightning, email, office-365

Our team is interested to [Send Email through Office 365](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_send_through_external.htm&type=5). Once enabled end user can login to office 365 using oauth in order to send email. The user can also decide to send email from office 365 or salesforce through their email setting.

[image]

The problem we are facing is Salesforce doesn't offer a way to block user from sending email from Salesforce.

Is there some obscure and hidden way I could prevent that or identify through apex if an email ([EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)) is sent from salesforce or office 365 ?

UPDATE
So far the only way we found is to enable multiple email relays, then config a dummy smtp with filter based on sender domain. The email is still sent but will not be received as it doesnt passed the smtp. Unfortunately the end user doesnt know that the email is not working.